# How to create image in PHP?

Tags: php

I am very new to create image in php.Basically i wanted to make static slider and values will come from database in terms of ratio.Suppose particular value is 0.9 then slider pointer will go at the very end of image

```
----------------
             | | 
----------------
```

How can i create this image?
please help.

Comment: the question isn't very clear: do you actually want to *create* the image in PHP, or just create dynamic links to images that already exist?

Comment: @ Spudley , I actually wanted to create image in png

Comment: If the slider portion is just a solid color, you can do this entirely with some html and css, without having to generate an image at all. `<div id="thermometer" style="width: 100px"><div id="filler" style="width:76px"></div></div>` would be the core of a progress bar that's at 76% full.

Answer (score 4):

There is a whole library for that called gd2. Here is how it works:

1) Be sure to activate it in your php.ini

2) Copy-paste:

```
<?php
header('Content-type:image/png');
$image = imagecreate(200, 50); // (x, y)
$background = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 127, 0); // The first color allocated is the background.
$red = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, 0, 10, 50, $red); // (x1, y1, x2, y2)
imagepng($image);
?>
```

3) On your page, use `<img src="image.php" />` like if it was a PNG.

4) There is no step 4.

You can also use the power of PHP, things such as loops and math are allowed. You can use $_GET, $_POST, $_SESSION, $_COOKIE, ...

For more questions about that: http://www.astahost.com/info.php/Basic-Tutorial-Php-Gd_t1203.html

Answer (score 2):

For a more generalized answer, if you take a look at the documentation on PHP's image support you'll see lots of methods relevant to you: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php

In particular, if you want to go down the GD route, you'd need to look at `imagecreate*` methods, and then (to dynamically draw your slider at a certain position) `imagefill*` (probably `imagefilledrectangle`).

Answer (score 0):

Sop log a progress metre ?

It's njot that complicated really, just take a look here:

- http://lasa-talkz.blogspot.com/2010/02/dynamic-progress-bar-with-php-gd.html

Although i would advise that you do not extract `$_GET` !!

Comment: thanks for the link its very useful but if i comment that line then it wont display anything

Comment: you would just use `$_GET['key']` instead of the extracted variables.